# text change while hovering using css

Tags: html, css, hover, mousehover

what I have used CSS that is correct, but if I use it two more times. same time change the text. I want to one by one hovering. I have tried this.

```css
.hexo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f6922d;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hexo:before,
.hexo:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
  transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
}

.hexo:before {
  left: -22px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

.hexo:after {
  right: -22px;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
}

div .comment {
  display: none;
}

div:hover .hexo {
  display: none;
}

div:hover .comment {
  display: inline;
}

.comment {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="hexo">Application Development</div>
    <div class="comment">Gathering requirements, designing prototypes, testing, implementation, and integration is what we perform</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hexo">Application Development</div>
    <div class="comment">Gathering requirements, designing prototypes, testing, implementation, and integration is what we perform
    </div>
  </div>
```

this thing I have tried anyone, please help me. how to change text one by one hovering

Comment: what would you like to archieve?

Comment: I need to create more hexagon shapes with text. while moving on the shape. content should appear. when the mouse hovers on one. should be change one. but here. hover on text all this thing changed.

Comment: While hovering on the topics few lines about the topic will appear.

Answer (score 0):

The effect gets triggered because you're hovering over the root div, so it's applied to all underlying `hexo` and `comment` elements.

You need to make sure that your styles only apply to child nodes, and not to all descendants:

```
div:hover > .hexo {
  display: none;
}

div:hover > .comment {
  display: inline;
}
```

**Complete snippet:**

```css
.hexo {
  height: 70px;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border-top: 4px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f6922d;
  line-height: 70px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hexo:before,
.hexo:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 13px;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 4px solid #000;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
  transform: scale(0.8, 1.25) rotate(45deg);
}

.hexo:before {
  left: -22px;
  border-top: 0px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
}

.hexo:after {
  right: -22px;
  border-bottom: 0px solid transparent;
  border-left: 0px solid transparent;
}

div .comment {
  display: none;
}

div:hover > .hexo {
  display: none;
}

div:hover > .comment {
  display: inline;
}

.comment {
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="hexo">Application Development</div>
    <div class="comment">Gathering requirements, designing prototypes, testing, implementation, and integration is what we perform</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="hexo">Application Development</div>
    <div class="comment">Gathering requirements, designing prototypes, testing, implementation, and integration is what we perform
    </div>
  </div>:
```

Comment: it's working thank you @robby Cornelissen